# ¿Cómo eliminar fila/s de una tabla guardada en una sessionStorage con javascript?

Tags: javascript, mvc

Tengo una tabla que muestra una lista de libros, por c/u de las filas de esa tabla tengo un botón *seleccionar libro*.

Al hacer clic en este boton, voy mostrando c/u de los libros seleccionados en otra tabla.

Para lograr esto internamente con `javascript` tengo una función `createTable()`. Dentro de esta función voy guardando los libros seleccionados en un `array`.

Los datos del `array` los paso a una tabla y guardo esa tabla en una `sessionStorage.setItem('tablaSeleccionados', table);`. La "*tablaSeleccionados*" tiene un botón *Eliminar* por cada libro.

A su vez, tengo otra funcion en javascript `function showTable()` que trae la tabla "*tablaSeleccionados*" que guarde en la `sessionStorage` para mostrarla en un `div`.

Lo que quiero hacer es que, cuando el usuario haga clic en el botón eliminar de la "*tablaSeleccionados*", desaparezca la fila que quiere eliminar, pero al mismo tiempo esa fila también debería desaparecer de la `sessionStorage`.

Caso contrario cuando vuelva a recargar la página, volvería a mostrarse la tabla sin los cambios.

Aca la `functión createTable()`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    //DECLARACION DE VARIABLES QUE SE VAN A USAR EN LAS FUNCIONES
    //traigo lo que esta guardado en las sessionStorage
    var json = sessionStorage.getItem("arrayId");
    var json2 = sessionStorage.getItem("arrayNames");

    //declaro los array
    var arrId = [];
    var arrNames = [];
    //si las sessionStorage no estan vacias se agrega su contenido a los array
    if (json != null) {
        arrId = JSON.parse(json);
        //show(arrId)
    }

    if (json2 != null) {
        arrNames = JSON.parse(json2);
        show(arrNames)
    }

    /////   Traigo la tabla guardada en sessionStorage  //////

    var body = sessionStorage.getItem('tablaSeleccionados');
    //muestro la tabla en el div #mDiv
    if (body != null) {
        $("#miDiv").append(sessionStorage.getItem('tablaSeleccionados'));
    }
    else {
        window.addEventListener("load", emptyTable, false);
    }

    function createTable(idLibro, nombreLibro) {

        var repeated = false;
        //guardo los idLibro y nombres de libro en los array
        arrId.push(idLibro);
        arrNames.push(nombreLibro);

        //Verifico que no haya datos duplicados en arrNames, si hay los borro
        var cantNombres = arrNames.length;

        if (cantNombres > 1) {

            for (var z = 0; z < cantNombres; z++) {

                var n = arrNames[z];

                for (var y = z + 1; y <= cantNombres; y++) {
                    if (n === arrNames[y]) {
                        //borro datos duplicados
                        arrNames.splice(y, 1);
                        arrId.splice(y, 1);
                        repeated = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //aviso de que el libro ya fue seleccionado
        if (repeated == true)
            alert("Usted ya seleccionó este libro")

        //guardo los array en sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem("arrayId", JSON.stringify(arrId));
        sessionStorage.setItem("arrayNames", JSON.stringify(arrNames));
        //tableItems.innerHTML = '';//limpio siempre el tbody para que Cuando vuelva a hacer click en el boton llenar tabla, no me duplique los elementos

        //traigo el array guardado en el sessionStorage
        var idBook = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("arrayId"));
        var names = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("arrayNames"));//traigo los nombre del libro
        var cantNames = names.length;//calculo cuantos elementos tiene
        var cont = 0;
        //************************creacion de tabla***********************************//

        var table = '<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tablaSeleccionados"><thead bgcolor="#2E4053"><tr><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Libros seleccionados</th><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Accion</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr></tr>';

        for (var i = 0; i < cantNames; i++) {

            table += '<tr>';
            table += '<td>' + names[i] + '</td>';
            table += '<td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)" class="boton2 btn" id="btnEliminar"' + " value=" + cont + ">Eliminar</button></td>";
            //table += '<td><button class="boton2 btn" id="btnEliminar"'+" value="+ idBook[i] +">Eliminar</button></td>";
            table += '</tr>';
            cont++;
        };

        table += '</tbody></table>';

        //************************Fin creacion de tabla*******************************//

        $('#miDiv').html(table);//muestra la tabla en el div #miDiv

        //guarda la tabla en una sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('tablaSeleccionados', table);

    }
```

Aca la `function showTable()`

```js
function showTable() {
        //muestra la tabla en el div #miDiv
        $("#miDiv").append(sessionStorage.getItem('tablaSeleccionados'));
    }
```

Y aca el `div` donde muestro la `tablaSeleccionados`

```html
<div id="table-wrapper">
        <div id="table-scroll">
            <div id="miDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Estoy intentando algo como esto, es decir que cuando haga clic en el botón eliminar, llame a una `function deleteRow()`.

Hasta aca funciona bien, la fila se borra, faltaría poder eliminar la `fila` de la `sessionStorage`.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    function deleteRow(r) {
        
        var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById("tablaSeleccionados").deleteRow(i);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: podrias utilizar la opcion fragemento javascript cuyo icono es `<>` para agregar un ejemplo funcional ya que el codigo esta a medias!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que intentas es algo como esto:

## nota: window.load ni sessionstorage funcionan en stackoverflow

```js
 // guardar en el sessionStorage
    function save(name){
     let current_id;
     let data = get();

  if(data){
   current_id = data["current_id"];
   data["libros"].push({"id":current_id, "name" : name});
   data["current_id"] = current_id+1;

  }else{
   data = {"current_id": 1,"libros":[]};
   data["libros"].push({"id":0, "name" : name});
  }

  sessionStorage.setItem("libros", JSON.stringify(data));

  return true;
    }

    // get datos del sessionStorage
    // si se especifica find es para buscar uno en concreto
    function get(find = null){
     let data = sessionStorage.getItem("libros");

  if(data){
   if(find){
    for(x in data["libros"]){
        if(parseInt(data["libros"][x].id) === parseInt(id)){
         return x;
        }
       }
      }
   return JSON.parse(data);
  }
  return false;
    }

    // eliminar del sessionStorage
    function del(id){
     let data = get();
     let postition = get(id);

     if(postition){
      data["libros"].splice(postition,1);
      sessionStorage.setItem("libros", JSON.stringify(data));
      return true;
     }
     return false;
    }

    // edita del sessionStorage
    function edit(id,name){
     let data = get();
     let postition = get(id);
     if(postition){
   data["libros"][postition]["name"] = name;
   sessionStorage.setItem("libros", JSON.stringify(data));
   return true;
     }
     return false;
    }
   
    // remover elementos tanto del session como del dom
    function remove(id){
     let el = document.querySelector('tbody tr[id="'+id+'"]');
     el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
     del(id);
    }

    // insertar elementos
    function insertRow(name){
     save(name);
     let data = get();

     if(data){
      let count = Object.keys(data["libros"]).length-1;
      createRow(data["libros"][count].id,data["libros"][count].name);
      return true;
     }

     return false;
    }

    // crear nuevas filas
    function createRow(id,name){
     //let table = '<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tablaSeleccionados"><thead bgcolor="#2E4053"><tr><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Libros seleccionados</th><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Accion</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';

     let data =get();
     let el = document.querySelector("tbody");

     let row = '<tr id="'+id+'">';
        row += '<td>' + name + '</td>';
        row += '<td><button onclick="remove('+id+')" class="boton2 btn" id="btnEliminar"' + " value=" + id + ">Eliminar</button>";
        //row += '<button onclick="editar('+id+')" class="boton2 btn" id="btnEliminar"' + " value=" + id + ">editar</button><td>";
        row += '</tr>';
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + row;
    }


    // mostrar todo lo guardado en el sessionstorage
    function showAll(){
     //si queremos que se pinte la tabla aun si no hay elementos

     let table = '<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tablaSeleccionados"><thead bgcolor="#2E4053"><tr><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Libros seleccionados</th><th scope="col" style="color:#ECF0F1">Accion</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';
     document.querySelector('#miDiv').innerHTML = table; 

     let data = get();
     if(data){
      for(x in data["libros"]){
       createRow(data["libros"][x].id,data["libros"][x].name);
      }
     }
    }

    // esperamos hasta que todo el documento carge.
    // nota: window.load ni sessionstorage funcionan en stackoverflow
    
    window.onload = showAll();
    //showAll();
    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     insertRow(e.target.querySelector("input").value);
     e.target.querySelector("input").value = "";
    })
```

```html
<div id="table-wrapper">
<!-- start test form -->
 <form action=""><input type="text" name="add" placeholder="Nombre Libro"> <button type="submit">add</button></form><br>
  <!-- end test form -->
        <div id="table-scroll">
            <div id="miDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```